# Postgres: handling null in where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Birt reporting which allows injecting parameter in a query as follow:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM foo 
WHERE bar = ?
```

The question mark comes from a drop down list. Among these values, 'All' can be selected, meaning there are no WHERE clause.

Is there a way to have conditional value in the WHERE clause such as below or an equivalent ?

```sql
WHERE
  CASE WHEN ? IS NULL 
  THEN 1=1
  ELSE bar = '%'
END
```

Comment: Something like `where(bar = ? or ? is null)`?

Comment: questionning my whole career now ... Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 3):

you can try something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo 
WHERE COALESCE(bar, '') = COALESCE(?, bar, '')
```

so, if argument is null - column will be compared with itself, which is almost always returns true, except weird logic around null values, this is why we need `coalesce` on both sides of equation

Comment: Geez I must say. Thanks it works !

Comment: Maybe I should open a new question, in which case I will, but can this be adapted if multiple values in the list are selected (kind on `IN ('p1', 'p2')` ?

Comment: @HeyStackExchange yeah, sure like `IN (coalesce(a,b,c...), coalesce(d,e,f...))`